# Why the java saveSpreadsheetRecords method limits in 65535 rows to write an xls file?

Tags: java, spring, xls

I'm implementing the snipet code bellow to export an xls file in the browser in a spring application :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = ResourcesPath.EXCEL,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void loadExcel(ReportFilter filter, HttpServletResponse response) throws
        IOException {

    List<ReportItemVO> result = // list of ReportItemVO ...
    Date today = new Date();
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=today.getTime() + ".xls");

    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    xlsExportService.saveSpreadsheetRecords(ReportItemVO.class, result, outputStream);

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}

public interface XlsExportService extends SpreadsheetService {
}
@Autowired
private XlsExportService xlsExportService;
```

Here everything works well when exporting data of result.size() < 65535. 
Otherwise "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)" is thrown.

I found that saveSpreadsheetRecords uses HSSFSheet which is limited in 65535 rows, and that I need to use a XSSHSheet, but I didn't find out any clue to use this in a way to have (ReportItemVO.class, result, outputStream) as an input.

Any idea please?

Comment: I didn't use EXCEL for a very long time, but if I can recall, EXCEL limit is 65535 rows per sheet.

Comment: Just change your HSSFSheet class to use XSSHSeet inside your service, it might require some other modifications but the XSSHSheet is an extension that supports xlsx. You will also have to return xlsx instead of xls otherwise Excel will give you the same error as well.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @locus2k I can't, it's a java interface in the package org.adorsys.xlseasy.annotation

Comment: Are you asking why there is a limit of 65535 rows, or how to use the XSSSheet class in this code snippet?

Comment: see my answer. you should implement `SpreedsheetService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be implementing `SpreedsheetService` not extending it

```
@Component
public class XlsExportService implements SpreedsheetService {

}
```

Then you can fill in the methods to use XSSFSheet instead of HSSFSheets

Comment: Hum! I agree, but in this case, the difficulty is I'll need to have a generic implementation to handle all my VO classes, which might need using reflection to get header of the xls and its values, then put everything together. What do you think?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: It is possible to write it in a generic way to fill the data you need. Might have to write a class that stores the information you need in which you will populate ahead of time with your VO information then pass it to the service to fill you spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

In the old Excel format of XLS, the maximum number of rows is 65535: [see this](https://www.excel-exercise.com/xls-xlsx-file/).

Try saving in XLSX format, that goes up to 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: How? did I just need to change the extension to xlsx?
If yes, It dosent't work